# YOLO Loss function decreasing accuracy

Tags: python, deep-learning, convolution, object-detection, yolo

I am having some issues implementing the YOLO loss function. Everytime I train my model, my loss decreases but my accuracy also decreases. This leads me to believe that my loss function is not correct. And considering the YOLO paper is quite vague, I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

Here is the loss function I am currently using attempting to follow the paper's function. I am attempting to find a single class object, therefore my y_true = [P,w,h,x,y] of the object, with no other bounding boxes.

```
def get_coord(X,Y,H,W):
x2 = X + W
y2 = Y + H

return x2,y2


def loss_function2(y_true,y_pred):
object_true = y_true[:,:,:,0]
object_pred = y_pred[:,:,:,0]

width_true = y_true[:,:,:,1]
width_pred = y_pred[:,:,:,1]

height_true = y_true[:,:,:,2]
height_pred =y_pred[:,:,:,2]

X_true = y_true[:,:,:,3]
X_pred =y_pred[:,:,:,3]

Y_true = y_true[:,:,:,4]
Y_pred = y_pred[:,:,:,4]

x2_true,y2_true = get_coord(X_true,Y_true,height_true,width_true)
x2_pred,y2_pred = get_coord(X_pred,Y_pred,height_pred,width_pred)

xi1 = tf.maximum(X_true,X_pred)
yi1 = tf.maximum(Y_true,X_true)
xi2 = tf.minimum(x2_true,x2_pred)
yi2 = tf.minimum(y2_true,y2_pred)


zeros = tf.zeros([10,19,19])

inter_area = tf.maximum(zeros,xi2-xi1)*tf.maximum(zeros,yi2-yi1)
box_area1 = (x2_true-X_true)*(y2_true-Y_true)
box_area2 = (x2_pred-X_pred)*(y2_pred-Y_pred)

union_area = box_area1 + box_area2 - inter_area
iou = inter_area/union_area

loss1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(object_true,(tf.squared_difference(X_pred,X_true) + tf.squared_difference(Y_pred,Y_true))))
loss2 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(object_true,(tf.squared_difference(tf.sqrt(width_pred),tf.sqrt(width_true)) + tf.squared_difference(tf.sqrt(height_pred),tf.sqrt(height_true)))))
loss3 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(object_true,(tf.squared_difference(object_pred,iou))))
loss4 = tf.scalar_mul(0.5,(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(((object_true*-1)+1),(tf.squared_difference(object_pred,object_true))))))

return loss1+loss2+loss3+loss4
```

I've split my image grid by 19x19, and so my the predictions come in batches of 10x19x19x5 tensors.

I've looked at the code from other implementations of YOLO in python, and most of the loss functions just puzzle me. They are either too complex for me to follow or implement something quite different than what the original paper has outlined.